# How to test this class independent of other class

Tags: apex

I have a class which uses scheduler interface. I am trying to implement a class which would send a report as an email notification to many people.

```
global class Open_Data_Report_Exporter implements Schedulable 
{

 global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

        try {
         sendRemEmail();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


global void sendRemEmail()
     {  system.debug('**************the query result is**********************:');

        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O55000000O3Mt?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('Open_Data_Report.csv');
        attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('Open Data Report');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'xyz@gmail.com' } );
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );

     }}
```

How can I test this in my local and see if I get a email notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to test depending on what you are wanting to do:

If you want to test the schedule simply schedule the class to run using the dev console. This example sets it to run every hour on the xx minute. Simply change the xx to the minute of the hour (say 2 minutes from the current time):

```
Open_Data_Report_Exporter p = new Open_Data_Report_Exporter();
String sch = '0 xx * * * ?';
system.schedule('My test Schedule', sch, p);
```

When it is done you can Setup -> monitor -> Scheduled jobs and delete the schedule

Or if you want to simply execute the method you can do so from the dev console as well:

```
Open_Data_Report_Exporter p = new Open_Data_Report_Exporter();
p.sendRemEmail();
```

In each case ensure the database has the appropriate records required to actually send the email

Comment: I get an error saying : Line: 1, Column: 14
Global type must be contained inside of a global class. Any Idea how I can resolve this. I am trying to send an email with report as an attachment.

Comment: @Rdvsm you can use `public` instead of `global` for schedulable classes unless doing managed package.  In addition, `sendRemEmail` could be declared as private if it is only invoked from the execute() method

Answer (score 1):

You can test this by executing the code inside of your method in Developer Console.

Your Name -> Developer Console -> Debug -> Open Execute Anonymous Code. Paste your code inside of your method and click Execute.

Hope it helps.